# Playwright Having issues selecting or interacting with page elements

Tags: typescript, object, frame, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to automate a few testcases but after logging in and navigating to the section the code keeps timing out. I tried recording the steps and get code like this:

```
await page.frameLocator('#obj_eXXXXX_wab_application').getByLabel('Logged In As:').selectOption('data_entry'); 
await page.frameLocator('#obj_eXXXXX_wab_application').getByRole('link', { name: 'New XXXX' }).click(); 
await page.frameLocator('#obj_eXXXXX_wab_application').getByRole('link', { name: 'My XXXX' }).click();
```

When I try to run this back I get the following error:

```
locator.selectOption: Error: Selector "#obj_eXXXXX_wab_application" resolved to <object type="text/html" _ngcontent-nhl-c9="" id="obj_ep…></object>, <iframe> was expected
```

This is what the elements look like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw9S6.png)

Here is the code from a recording:

```html
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('about:blank');
    await page.goto('https://xxxx.xxx.xxx/portal/');
    await page.getByPlaceholder('User ID').fill('username');
    await page.getByLabel('Password', { exact: true }).fill('password');
    await page.getByLabel('Password', { exact: true }).click();
    await page.getByLabel('Welcome to Login Section. All').getByText('I agree to the Terms and').click();
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' }).click();
    await page.getByText('xxxx TEST').click();
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Application' }).click();
    //from here I get the error and test fail
    await page.frameLocator('#obj_xxxx_wab_application').getByLabel('Logged In As:').selectOption('data_entry');
    await page.frameLocator('#obj_xxxx_wab_application').getByLabel('Logged In As:').selectOption('data_extractor');
    await page.frameLocator('#obj_xxxx_wab_application').getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click();
  });
```

I've tried different types of selectors and xpaths.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with the website you're working with (or a minimal repro of it). Thanks.

Comment: Added some of it. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, but still incomplete. I can't access `https://xxxx.xxx.xxx/portal/`. There's no way to really help without something I can run, see the problem, and experiment with. That said, the error seems pretty self explanatory, in that you're using `frameLocator` to select an `<object>`, but `frameLocator` only works when you select an `<iframe>`.

Comment: Sorry I cant share the actual site. The frameLocator is what I get when I record the steps. How can I select an <object>? I've tried using xpaths for the object but it didnt work. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: The opposite: select the iframe, not the object. If you're using a recorder, it might be misfiring and you can fix the code by hand.

Comment: Thats just it, there are no iframes on the page.

Comment: Then use locators instead of frame locators?

Comment: I used locator with xpaths but it keeps timing out when it gets to that statement.

Comment: Why xpaths? You have an id that's unique on the page, so a CSS selector is the easiest way to leverage it: `.locator('#obj_eXXXXX_wab_application')`. We're sort of going in circles here. Without the actual site and a clear description of what you're trying to achieve on it, all I can do is make random guesses, which doesn't help you much.